# If $f: X \to Y$ is injective and continuous, then $f^{-1}$ is an open map from image of $f$ to $X$.

Tags: functions

So this is a simple question but I cannot seem to find an answer online. To me it is clear that this is true. Since $f$ is injective, $f^{-1}$ is well defined (as a map from the image of $f$ to $X$. Now since $f$ is continuous, any preimage of an open set is open, thus it would seem that $f^{-1}$ simply maps open sets to open sets. Is this correct?

Comment: Be careful asserting $f^{-1}$ is well-defined. Surjectivity gives that an inverse exists. You have to restrict the range of $f$ to guarantee this.

Comment: @bounceback That is what I did in the title. I can add it in the main question. Le tme fix it.

Comment: OK gotcha, I see now. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is as simple as it sounds. The inverse image of a subset of $Y$ under $f$ is, by injectivity, the (forward) image of the same set under $f^{-1}$.